# How to fix the black screen issue before installing Ubuntu16

Tags: 16.04, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I want to install dual systems through USB flash disk, win10+ubuntu16, and now win10 is ok, then I try to install ubuntu16, just like the image show, there are maybe some problem with my graphics card on ubuntu, and I have search a lot, still can not fix this prob.

my Graphics Card is **'GTX 1070'**

select 'Install Ubuntu'
[image]

then I got this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After search and try, then I find the solution,

just as the first image above, select `Install Ubuntu`, then type `e` then replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`, then press `F10` to boot